# How to install Lubuntu to an external USB drive as part of a dual boot?

Tags: dual-boot, windows, lubuntu, usb-drive, windows-10

I have an external USB drive that I currently have Windows 10 installed on. I used the tool [WinToUSB](http://www.easyuefi.com/wintousb/) to install Windows 10 on that drive. Windows runs directly from the drive. It's a portable installation that I can take anywhere I want and use on a variety of computers.

I want to have a dual boot from the same external USB drive. (Windows 10 and Lubuntu 16.04.)

I prefer a real installation of Lubuntu rather than a persistent. This is because a 4GB persistent image is not enough space for my needs.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what i understand you don't want software like MultiBootUSB, YUMI or MultiSystem. You already installed WindowsToGo, all you need to do is create linux partition after Windows partition and install Lubuntu to it just like you would install it to any other hard-disk. Your USB drive will be probably listed as sdb, sdc, etc. Make sure you don't mistake it for hda or sda, that being the internal hard-disk of your PC. And make sure GRUB (LUbuntu's bootloader) will install to /sdb (the root of your USB drive), otherwise Lubuntu will remain installed but unavailable.

Comment: Sounds good, I'll try it.